# How to find current timezone id

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, timezone

I am trying to use `AT TIME ZONE` of SQL Server to get server date time for certain UTC date.

But `AT TIME ZONE` requires to pass the timezone id of the timezone.

But somehow I am not able to find the way to get timezone id of server timezone in SQL Server in the format this function expects.

There does exist a function `CURRENT_TIMEZONE()` but it is also not returning the timezone id.

I found this function also [CURRENT_TIMEZONE_ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-timezone-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), but I am not able to find it in SQL Server 2019, the description looks like it is for Azure specifically.

So is there any way through which rather than passing the hardcoded timezone id like this, I can use something which will pick the current timezone id of the server

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), '2015-03-29T01:01:00', 126)     
AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time';
```

Comment: Neither of these are particularly pretty, but you could try getting the end part of `SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` to get the hours, or get it from your computer's registry  `DECLARE @TimeZone VARCHAR(50); 
EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation',
'TimeZoneKeyName',@TimeZone OUT;
SELECT @TimeZone;` - taken from https://tsql.how/get-current-timezone-of-server/

Comment: The problem is `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` gives current datetime offset of the server but I want to get the datetime offset of particular date in past which I can only get or convert my date using `AT TIME ZONE` only

Comment: "I want to get the datetime offset of particular date in past which I can only get or convert my date using AT TIME ZONE only" What if the time zone of the server have changed since that date? and why should you care what is the local datetime of the server anyway?

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . Lots of businesses run on local time and need to day daylight saving time into account.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not arguing against that, I'm arguing against the assumption that the local time of the server is somehow relevant. It's a server. It might be on prem or on a cloud, it might be running on a server farm in a different state (with a different time zone)... My point is, the local settings on the server shouldn't be important.

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . That makes sense.  I'm actually glad I asked for the clarification, because you make a good point.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - `"and why should you care what is the local datetime of the server anyway?"` This is a subjection question. The local timezone matter for me because my software is on premise software so I will never have the condition where the sql server will be situated in some different place.
`What if the time zone of the server have changed since that date?` That is actually I want to know that when the date and hours offset are changing to fetch the project data for any date range. That is the all requirement.

Comment: If the time zone of the server was changed, I doubt you'll be able to find it via SQL Server. You'll probably be able to get that information from the events log (at least, based on my [quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=is+it+possible+to+log+a+time+zone+change+on+a+windows+server%3F&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIL883IL883&oq=is+it+possible+to+log+a+time+zone+change+on+a+windows+server%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57.15687j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))

Comment: @ZoharPeled - Actually I tried seanb solution (the first comment). It works even when I change my machine's timezone manually. And actually I just want to get the timezone id, that is all my requirement is, because once I get that id I have the code to get the past date for that time zone.

Comment: Yes, that should get you the time zone information currently set on the server. I thought you wanted to know what was the time zone set to in past dates.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - No, I just wanted to know the current timezone id because that can give me any date correctly in past also. Because my server timzone will never change.
Do you know it there is any better or direct way to know the current timezone id? Because the suggested solution requires to read the registry. Any equivalent of this function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-timezone-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @PawanNogariya - Must it be done in SQL?  Or are you calling SQL from an application layer where this would be easier?  For example, in .NET you could use `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id` and pass that as a parameter to SQL if needed.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint - Yes, must be in SQL only :( Cannot pass it from c# code due to many constraints

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any CURRENT\_TIMEZONE\_ID equivalent function in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64748057/is-there-any-current-timezone-id-equivalent-function-in-sql-server)